# Табы на JavaScript, проблема c реализацией

Tags: javascript

Есть код и он работает, но нужно чтобы бы он сам по нужному клику выбирался нужный блок.

```js
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName('q');
var par = document.getElementsByClassName('w');
        
for (var i=0;i<btns.length;i++) {
    switch(i) {
        case 0 : btns[i].onclick = function(){
            for(i=0; i<btns.length; i++){
                par[i].classList.remove("active");
                par[0].classList.add("active");
            }
        }
            break;
        case 1 : btns[i].onclick = function(){
            for(i=0; i<btns.length; i++){
                par[i].classList.remove("active");
                par[1].classList.add("active");
            }
            
        }
        break;
        case 2 : btns[i].onclick = function(){
            for(i=0; i<btns.length; i++){
                par[i].classList.remove("active");
                par[2].classList.add("active");
            }
            
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

```css
.q{
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.w{
    display: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.active{
    display: block;
}
.tabs{
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="dis">

    <div class="tabs">
        <div class="q">payment</div>    
        <div class="q">order</div>      
        <div class="q">any one</div>
    </div>
        <div class="w active"><p>loerm ipsum1111</p></div>
        <div class="w"><p>loerm ipsum222</p></div>
        <div class="w"><p>loerm ipsum333</p></div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: А в чем собственно вопрос?

Comment: Автоматизировать код, сейчас он работает вручную. блоки которые появляются при нажатие прописаны в ручную par[0,1,2,3,4,5 и т.д].classList.add("active");

Comment: вынеси одинаковый код в функцию и сделай обычный цикл без switch

Comment: а если не сложно можно на примере показать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем так усложнять?

Вешаете клик на элемент `tabs`, через [делегирование событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation) проверяете, было ли нажатие на элемент `.q`, если да - то:
Для смены на "активный" у `.tabs`

1. Ищите элемент `.q.active` и удаляете класс `.active`
2. Добавляете класс `.active` нажатому элементу

Для смены на "активный" у `.content`. (для удобства советую обернуть все `.w` в блок, будет у нас `.content`)

1. Получаете индекс нажатого элемента `.q`
2. Находите `.w.active` и удаляете класс `.active`
3. Находите элемент по индексу нажатого и добавляете класс `.active`

```js
let tabs = document.querySelector('.tabs'),
    content = document.querySelector('.content');
    
tabs.addEventListener('click', function(e) { // Вешаем обработчик
  if(e.target.classList.contains('q')) { // Проверяем нажатие на элемент `.w`
    // СМЕНА ССЫЛОК
    let target = e.target; // Это нажатый элемент
    if(target.classList.contains('active')) return false; // Если элемент уже активный, то не выполняем действия ниже 
    this.querySelector('.q.active').classList.remove('active'); // находим в `.tabs` активный элемент и "деактивируем"
    target.classList.add('active'); // А нажатый активируем
   
    // СМЕНА КОНТЕНТА
    let index = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.children).indexOf(target); // Получаем индекс нажатого элемента
    content.querySelector('.w.active').classList.remove('active'); // Деактивируем
    content.querySelectorAll('.w')[index].classList.add('active'); // активируем
  }
});
```

```css
.q {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.q.active {
  color: green;
}

.w {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.w.active {
  display: block;
}

.tabs {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="dis">

  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="q active">payment</div>
    <div class="q">order</div>
    <div class="q">any one</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="w active">
      <p>loerm ipsum1111</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w">
      <p>loerm ipsum222</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w">
      <p>loerm ipsum333</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

А лучше всего вручную добавить какой-то одинаковый идентификатор элементам `.q` и `.w`, чтобы было проще их найти и не перепутать.

```js
let tabs = document.querySelector('.tabs'),
    content = document.querySelector('.content');
    
tabs.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('q')) {
    let target = e.target,
        id = target.getAttribute('data-id');
    if(target.classList.contains('active')) return false;
    this.querySelector('.q.active').classList.remove('active');
    target.classList.add('active');
   
    content.querySelector('.w.active').classList.remove('active');
    content.querySelector('.w[data-id="'+id+'"]').classList.add('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.q {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.q.active {
  color: green;
}

.w {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.w.active {
  display: block;
}

.tabs {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="dis">

  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="q active" data-id="item-1">payment</div>
    <div class="q" data-id="item-2">order</div>
    <div class="q" data-id="item-3">any one</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="w active" data-id="item-1">
      <p>loerm ipsum1111</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w" data-id="item-2">
      <p>loerm ipsum222</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w" data-id="item-3">
      <p>loerm ipsum333</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Дело в том что блоки с контентом и самим табом добавляются, можно сказать автоматически и изменять каждый по отдельности в ручную невозможно...
Второй способ подошёл бы, если бы можно было автоматически давать блоку какой-то одинаковый идентификатор. А возможно я и ошибаюсь, поэтому и попросил помощи)

Comment: Первый вариант использует индекс элемента (порядковый номер), этот вариант вам не помог?

Comment: в одном табе может быть несколько блок с контентом

Comment: Не совсем понимаю о чём вы.
Если речь идёт о том, что внутри `.w` будет что-то другое - да хоть полноценный магазин, всё что угодно и будет работать. Если речь идёт о том, что внутри табов есть другие табы, то это уже другая проблема.

Comment: В общем, чтобы мне тут не гадать, почему мой вариант вам не помог - измените свой вопрос, добавив уточнения.