# Помогите с реализацией табов на js

Tags: javascript, css

Как создать полноценные табы такому html коду, у меня пока не хватает опыта чтобы самому это сделать. Нужно чтобы при открытие таба, текст был в начале, и `tab1 tab2 tab3` не сдвигались при появлении контента. Можно ли это реализовать? Заранее спасибо

```js
let par = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');

par.forEach(function(e) {
  e.onclick = function() {
    let tab1 = this.nextElementSibling;
    tab1.classList.toggle('acctive');
  }
});
```

```css
.asd {
  display: flex;
}

.tab {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}

.acctive {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="asd">
  <div class="n1">
    <div class="tab">
      tab1
    </div>
    <div class="content acctive">
      lorem ipsum111
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="n2">
    <div class="tab">
      tab2
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      lorem ipsum222
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="n3">
    <div class="tab">
      tab3
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      lorem ipsum333
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Посмотрите [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1373725) вариант.

Comment: там табы по другому написаны в html, там они в одном блоке, а тут в разных, не знаю как их реализовать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишу немного не очень правильного кода, но рабочего, основной хак тут использование абсолютного позиционирования, но так же фикс высоты через js. Надеюсь вам будёт полезно :)

```js
let par = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
let lastActive = null;

// Компенсирует высоту родителя высотами элементов
const fixHeight = (parent, ...elements) => {
    const fullHeight = elements.reduce((prev, value) => {
      return prev + value.offsetHeight;
    }, 0);

    parent.style.height = `${fullHeight}px`;
}

par.forEach(function(e) {
  const tabContent = e.nextElementSibling;
  
  // если таб был уже активирован через html:
  
  // eсли было активировано больше одного таба, закроем все кроме первого
  if (lastActive && tabContent.classList.contains("active")) {
    tabContent.classList.toggle("active");
  }
  
  // запоминаем последний активный таб
  if (tabContent.classList.contains("active")) {
    lastActive = tabContent;
    
    // Так, как контент размещён абсолютно компенсируем высоту родителя на высоту контента активного таба
    const tabsParent = e.closest(".asd");
    fixHeight(tabsParent, e, tabContent);
  }
  // --------------------------------------------
  
  e.onclick = function() {         
    let tab1 = this.nextElementSibling;
    
    // закрываем предыдущий таб, если уже один был открыт  
    if (lastActive) lastActive.classList.toggle('active');
    
    tab1.classList.toggle('active');
    
    // Так, как контент размещён абсолютно компенсируем высоту родителя на высоту контента активного таба
    const tabsParent = tab1.closest(".asd");
    fixHeight(tabsParent, this, tab1);
    
    // запоминаем активный таб в переменную
    lastActive = tab1;
  }
});
```

```css
.asd{
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
}
.tab{
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.content{
  display:none;
}
.active{
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="asd">
    <div class="n1">
        <div class="tab">
            tab1
        </div>
        <div class="content active">
            lorem ipsum111
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="n2">
        <div class="tab">
            tab2
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            lorem ipsum222
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="n3">
        <div class="tab">
            tab3
        </div>
        <div class="content active">
            lorem ipsum333
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

При клике, прежде, чем показать новый таб - надо спрятать все остальные.
А выравнивание табов сделать через абсолютное позиционирование

```js
let par = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
let contenNodes = document.querySelectorAll('.content');
function hideAll () {
    contenNodes.forEach(cNode => {
        cNode.classList.remove('acctive');
    });
}    
par.forEach(function(e){
    e.onclick = function(){
        hideAll();
        let tab1 = this.nextElementSibling;
        tab1.classList.toggle('acctive');
    }
});
```

```css
.asd {
      display:flex;
  }
  .tab {
      margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .content {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      display:none;
  }
  .acctive {
      display:block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="asd">
    <div class="n1">
        <div class="tab">
            tab1
        </div>
        <div class="content acctive">
            lorem ipsum111
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="n2">
        <div class="tab">
            tab2
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            lorem ipsum222
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="n3">
        <div class="tab">
            tab3
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            lorem ipsum333
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Заметил что при абсолютном позиционирование, блоки что находятся ниже не сдвигаются вниз, например если у меня будет футер, то он будет сливаться с содержимым табов. Можно ли как-то это исправить?

Comment: С учетом такой верстки - только если задать фиксированную высоту для .asd 
А если всё же важно, чтобы табы подстраивались под контент, то absolute никак не подойдёт и тогда придётся делать более традиционным способом: кнопки табов отдельно и сами табы - ниже под кнопками табов тоже отдельными div.