# Как открывать блоки на кнопки с data-атрибутом?

Tags: javascript, html

Как при нажатии кнопки с data-атрибутом открывать блок привязаный к нему?

```
<button class="btn-more" data-case="item1">подробнее</button>
<button class="btn-more" data-case="item2">подробнее</button>
<button class="btn-more" data-case="item3">подробнее</button>

<div class="portfolio__content">

    <div class="block1" data-item="item1"></div>
    <div class="block2" data-item="item2"></div>
    <div class="block3" data-item="item3"></div>

</div>
```

```
const caseBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-more');
const caseCloseBtn = document.querySelector('.close__content');
const caseContent = document.querySelector('.portfolio__content');

caseBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  caseContent.classList.add('case__active');
  document.body.classList.add('overflowhidden');
  $('ul.tabs#portfolio').appendTo('.portfolio__content .pc__container .pc__header');
});

caseCloseBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  caseContent.classList.remove('case__active');
  document.body.classList.remove('overflowhidden');
  $('ul.tabs#portfolio').appendTo('.portfolio__headers');
});
```

Можете подсказать как сделать чтобы кнопки находились не в одном классе, как в вашем случае: (для  De.Minov )

```
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="q active" data-id="item-1">payment</div>
    <div class="q" data-id="item-2">order</div>
    <div class="q" data-id="item-3">any one</div>
</div>

А например так:

<div class="tabs">
    <div class="q" data-id="item-1">payment</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="q" data-id="item-2">payment</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="q" data-id="item-3">payment</div>
  </div>


tabs.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('q')) {
    let target = e.target,
        id = target.getAttribute('data-id');
    if(target.classList.contains('active')) return false;
    this.querySelector('.q.active').classList.remove('active');
    target.classList.add('active');
   
    content.querySelector('.w.active').classList.remove('active');
    content.querySelector('.w[data-id="'+id+'"]').classList.add('active');
  }
});
```

Comment: Такая штука называет табы (или вкладки), [вот мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1373736/221218) на похожий вопрос, там есть реализация с использованием дата-атрибутов

Comment: Можете подсказать как сделать чтобы кнопки находились не в одном классе, как в вашем случае? Измнеил вопрос, снизу код

Comment: Эм, а что мешает использовать код моей вёрстки по аналогии "например так"?